# Vue3.js how to render html with component tag?

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs3, inertiajs

I'm trying to render html with some defined syntax. And I change the syntax to the Vue component tag `ProductRow`

When i using it like this, it will work.

```js
computed: {
    productRow() {
        return defineAsyncComponent(() => import("@/Component/ProductRow"))
    }
}
```

```html
<component :is="productRow" :product="product"></component>
```

But, I need it render combine with some html (from server and can be changed) like:

```html
<div>
    <product-row :product="product"/>
</div>
```

How should I do? Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: Either add this DIV within the ProductRow component or add it in the parent component. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Thomas Sorry, the div is come from the server, and can be changed any time~